# Firebase Phone Auth and Phone number Selector

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

At Google IO's This session https://youtu.be/MUULwaxqFLI?t=35m36s
He says we can get Phone number automatically with Phone number Selector
But he showed that with AuthUI On the other hand New Version of Auth Ui is not release yet.

And If i want to implements Auto Phone number selection then what should i do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. FirebaseUI 2.0 is now available with phone number auth support:
   https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md
2. To use the phone number picker, use HintRequest in below doc and configure:

   new HintRequest.Builder()
           .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
           .setEmailAddressIdentifierSupported(false)
           .build();

https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-hints

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)